# Can't import google_play_services-lib using eclipse

Tags: google-play-services

I re-installed google_play_services successfully and I have google_play_services-lib in my workspace. When I try to import it as a project in eclipse I use File-> Import->Existing Projects into Workspece -> Next -> Select root directory and then I find and select google_play_services-lib but finally it says "no project found to import". Why is that? How can I import this lib into eclipse?

I forgot to mention that I followed the steps at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then the reason you cannot import it is because you have already imported it. If the Google Play Services code is outside Eclipse and you have updated those directories then the job is done !

However if you copied the code into the Eclipse workspace then the easiest approach may be to delete the GPGS lib from Eclipse and then import again.

Comment: Oh no, It was not already imported. But I solved the problem in a very unexpected way. I fancy I should try to import the archive (the zip file containing the google-play-services directory.) And it worked!!! lol!

Comment: Now I still have to make my application run, using Google maps ... and it does not. I receive a Fatal Exception: Error inflating class fragment in the XML layout file. OMG! What am I to do? Perhaps ask a new question on the forum :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same Problem. What I did:
File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace
That worked for me.